# Wordpress and Polylang: Confilct with ‘wp_insert_post_data’ and post name from meta fields

Tags: wordpress, polylang

I’ve my custom posts types and polylang works great with them.

But, trying to speed up the inserting process, when I post a new post, I don’t need to write the name, because it is automatically get by combining 2 metas.
Here is the script I use (no credit for me, I got it from here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94364/set-post-title-from-two-meta-fields)

```
<?php function title_from_meta( $data , $postarr ) {

// We only care if it's my type
if( $data[ 'post_type' ] === 'mytype' ) {

    // get name from _POST or from post_meta
    $mytitle = ( ! empty( $_POST[ 'meta1' ] ) && ! empty( $_POST[ 'meta2' ] )  ) 
                    ? $_POST[ 'meta1' ] . $_POST[ 'meta2' ] 
                    : get_post_meta( $postarr[ 'ID' ], 'meta1', true ) . get_post_meta( $postarr[ 'ID' ], 'meta2', true );

    // if the name is not empty, we want to set the title
    if( $mytitle !== '' ) {

        // sanitize name for title
        $data[ 'post_title' ] = $mytitle;
        // sanitize the name for the slug
        $data[ 'post_name' ]  = sanitize_title( sanitize_title_with_dashes( $mytitle, '', 'save' ) );
    }
}
return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'title_from_meta' , '99', 2 );
```

PROBLEM:
When I click on post, I get the right permalinks:
http://example.com/en/my-post-type-slug/postname
http://example.com/fr/my-post-type-slug/postname-2

(where post name = meta1meta2)

but, if I try to access those addresses wordpress finds nothing and the links to the other language doen’t work…

I did try to deactivate or reactivate the plugins, resave the permalinks structure, but nothing works. Works only if I comment out that piece of code… any Ideas? Thanks!!